What should i do about error 1064 in mysql wamp console
Im just starting sql and did exactly what tutorial said but im getting a lot of error im using mysql 8.2 in wamp and trying to do this
I tried this and got syntax error i even reduced a lot of it and still got error i tried

Hi, show the code you tried, show all of the error messages, and please do it in text format, thank you.  If you want to look at the database side of the program versus the winamp side, you might look into MySQL Workbench to interact with the database visually, so you aren't relying on command line commands to solve this.

Im trying to make a table in the tutorial it goes like CREATE TABLE subjcts(

Im trying to make a table in the tutorial it goes like CREATE TABLE subjcts(  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, menu_name VARCHAR NOT NULL, position INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id) ); i even reduced a lot and still got error i tried CREATE TABLE subjects(id INT, menu_name VARCHAR);

You need to provide the size for VARCHAR datatype in MySQL.
VARCHAR (256) , but see the other thread at the top of this question because its now closed.
